# Egrep: contains and does not contain

Tags: grep, regular-expression, pipe

```
egrep -i '12-12.*\swarning' log.file | cless
```

The above will produce two lines with the date `12-12`, followed by random characters, a white space, then `Warning` and more text.

```
2011-12-12 textetc Warning 1234
2011-12-12 textetc Warning 5678
```

I wish it only to return lines that DO NOT contain 1234 at the end. I'm using GNU grep 2.5.4.

Currently, this is my workaround.

```
egrep -i '12-12.*\swarning' log.file > tmp.txt
egrep -i -v '1234' tmp.txt
```

I've tried piping the first to the second (without creating a file), but it either returns way too much, and it's all wrong, or it returns nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use 2 `grep`s.

```
grep -i '12-12.*[[:space:]]warning' log.file | grep -v '1234$'
```

Alternatively, you could use one `awk`

```
awk '/12-12.*[[:space:]]warning/ && ! /1234$/' log.file
```

Comment: Thanks! You solved my issue with the first line. My problem was that I thought I had to add the file I was grepping in the second statement.